# How to display variables' constantly changing values in console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got an object like this: `{"symbol1": 0, "symbol2": 0}` and the values in it are constantly changing.

I would like to display the object's pairs in console in a format like this and update them every second:

```
symbol1: 0
symbol2: 0
```

I tried using `process.stdout.write` and update it every second with `setInterval` but it only displayed the first symbol. I would like to include all the symbols from the object, each on a new line and update the values every second, so the user can see the current values without scrolling.

Any help much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this library if anyone's looking for something similar https://github.com/ivanseidel/node-draftlog

Answer (score 0):

```
var stuff = {"symbol1": 0, "symbol2": 0};

setInterval(function () {

  Object.keys(stuff).forEach(e => { // loop in the keys
    console.log(`${e}: ${stuff[e]}`); // print the element and it's value
  });
}, 1000);
```

Does this works?

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes, it works but not in the way I'm thinking about. I would like to update the same lines over and over. Something like a progress bar that stays in the same line, so there's no scrollbar in the console at all.

Comment: does this works? https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress

Comment: That is great, I'll make use of it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function periodicallyPrint()
{
  console.log(`${yourGameObject}`)
  return Promise.delay(1000 /*period in ms*/).then(() => periodicallyPrint());
}
```

Call this function to start the printing. It will print forever, so you may want to add a bool holding whether it should continue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's a nice approach but I was thinking about forcing it to stay in the same line, think of it like a progress bar.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bubkoo/ascii-progress/master/snapshot.gif